# Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move_and_slide()

Tags: godot, gdscript

I was following a tutorial for a script which makes a sprite follow another, the tutorial used Godot3.X whilst I use Godot 4. When it got to the point where I had to add move and slide to make the sprite able to move, it gave me errors.

```
extends CharacterBody2D
var speed = 200
var motion = Vector2.ZERO
const FLOOR_NORMAL: Vector2 = Vector2(0, -1)
var player = null

func _physics_process(delta):
    motion = Vector2.ZERO
    if player:
        motion = position.direction_to(player.position) * speed
    motion = move_and_slide(motion)



func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):
    print("entered")
    player = body

func _on_area_2d_body_exited(body):
    print ("exit")
    player = null
```

This is the code that is giving the error (motion = move_and_slide(motion), is giving the error)
This is intended to move a sprite towards the player. The move and slide allows it to move, or it should.
My current assumption is that this is a Godot 4 problem but feel free to prove that assumption wrong.
It says "Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 1." as the error.
I hope someone has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What I describe in this answer applies to both `CharacterBody2D` and `CharacterBody3D`.*

---

In Godot 4 the method `move_and_slide` takes no arguments.

Instead, you set the properties of the `CharacterBody2D`. In this case, instead of passing `motion`, you would set the `velocity`:

```
velocity = motion
move_and_slide()
motion = velocity
```

The intention is that you use `velocity` directly, instead of declaring your own vector (which you called `motion`). So remove `motion` and use `velocity` directly. Like this:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if player:
        velocity = position.direction_to(player.position) * speed

    move_and_slide()
```

**Note**: *As I explain below...* **Do not declare `velocity`**, the character body already has a `velocity` property, you do not need to add one.

You might also want to set other properties. In particular the `motion_mode`. Since you were not passing an UP vector, I assume you don't want the `CharacterBody2D` to distinguish floor, walls, and ceiling, in which case you use the "Floating" motion mode. Otherwise, leave it on "Grounded". If you want to specify said UP vector, you find it in the `up_direction` property.

---

### Pick Godot 4 tutorials

*I hope this section helps people searching for this problem.*

In Godot 3 `move_and_slide` did take multiple arguments. It was common to see calls such as `move_and_slide(velocity)` or `move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)`. If you find that in a tutorial, it is a Godot 3 tutorial, which is not what you want if you are working in Godot 4.

Of course in Godot 4 using that code results in the error `"Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 1."`

Here are some things might hint if if you are looking at a Godot 3 tutorial or a Godot 4 tutorial:

Godot 3:

- `onready` is a keyword.
- The 3D Node class is called `Spatial`.
- The characters in 3D are made with `KinematicBody`, and in 2D with `KinematicBody2D`.
- They might declare `velocity` or a similar variable.
- `move_and_slide` returns a velocity, and takes a velocity as first parameter among other things. So code looks like this:

  ```
  velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
  ```

Godot 4:

- `@onready` is an annotation.
- The 3D Node class is called `Node3D`.
- The characters in 3D are made with `CharacterBody3D`, and in 2D with `CharacterBody2D`.
- They do not declare `velocity` or similar variable, instead they just use the built-in `velocity` property.
- `move_and_slide` takes no parameter, returns if there was a collision (`bool`) and works with the properties of the `CharacterBody3D`/`CharacterBody2D` (such as `velocity` and `up_direction`). So code looks like this:

```
move_and_slide()
```

*I've adapted this list from an answer in the game development sister site ([link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/206841/10408)).*

---

### Adapting Godot 3 code to Godot 4

So you got some Godot 3 code that you want to translate to Godot 4, and there is a call to `move_and_slide` where they pass a velocity, and perhaps some other arguments. What to do?

First of all, you do **not need to declare `velocity`**. Your `CharacterBody2D`/`CharacterBody3D` already have a `velocity` property, so set that.

i.e. instead of this:

```
move_and_slide(something)
```

You want to do this:

```
velocity = something
move_and_slide()
```

**Don't do** the following (in the following example we are shadowing the `velocity` property with our own `velocity` variable, which won't work as expected):

```
var velocity = something # <- DON'T DO THIS
move_and_slide()
```

In the above examples `something` refers to whatever computation you had there. For example if you had something like this:

```
move_and_slide(direction * speed)
```

Then now you do this

```
velocity = direction * speed
move_and_slide()
```

I hope that makes sense.

---

Perhaps you had code that looked more like this:

```
move_and_slide(something, some_up_vector)
```

Then you do this:

```
velocity = something
up_direction = some_up_vector
move_and_slide()
```

For a more concrete example, that might look like this:

```
velocity = direction * speed
up_direction = Vector3.UP
move_and_slide()
```

*Of course, for 2D that woudl be `Vector2.UP` instead of `Vector3.UP`.*

**Note**: for `up_direction` to work, you also want `motion_mode` to be set to `MOTION_MODE_GROUNDED` (which you can set from the inspector). The `up_direction` is used in conjunction with `floor_max_angle` to discriminate if the body is on the floor, a wall, or ceiling.

---

I hope the pattern is clear: what you passed as arguments to `move_and_slide` are now properties you set before calling it (that could be setting them in the inspector, right before the call, or whenever it is appropiate).

Here is the complete list (in order): `velocity`, `up_direction`, `stop_on_slope`, (there is no equivalent for the `max_slides` parameter), `floor_max_angle`, (there is no equivalent for the `infinite_inertia` parameter, in general it is no longer necessary).

---

**On the return value of `move_and_slide`:**

About the return value: In Godot 3 `move_and_slide` used to return the final `velocity`. Now it updates the `velocity` property, so you can read it after calling `move_and_slide`. However, if you are working with the `velocity` property chances are that you do not need to. And as stated before, In Godot 4 `move_and_slide` returns a `bool`, which tells you if there was any collision (including slides).