# Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 1

Tags: godot, godot4

So, I was following a tutorial for making my enemy move towards my player, and there comes a part of the script where its calls a "Move_Slide" so the enemy can move, but I get the error.

Heres my full code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

# Movement speed
var speed = 100 
var player_position
var target_position
# Get a reference to the player. 
@onready var player = get_parent().get_node("Player")
 
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    # Set player_position to the position of the player node
    player_position = player.position
    # Calculate the target position
    target_position = (player_position - position).normalized()
 
    
    if position.distance_to(player_position) > 1:
        move_and_slide(target_position * speed)
        look_at(player_position)
```

the error is located at the part of the script "move_and_slide(target_position * speed)"

I've looked on Stack Overflow for this problem and I found a answer but this is for if i call a motion witch I don't so that doesn't help me.

Comment: I'm linking this related question here to make it easier for people to find it:  [Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move_and_slide()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75869903/402022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling `move_and_slide()` on a `CharacterBody2D` in Godot 4.  Your current code would work fine for a `KinematicBody2D` in Godot 3.x but in Godot 4 a KinematicBody2D was replaced with CharacterBody2D.

A CharacterBody2D has a `velocity` property and it uses this property to determine the updates necessary in the `move_and_slide()` method.  Hence, you don't need to pass in a velocity argument - you need to update the velocity property.

Try something like:

```
    if position.distance_to(player_position) > 1:
        velocity.x = target_position.x * speed;
        velocity.y = target_position.y * speed;
        move_and_slide()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally worked for me! so if I'm understanding correctly (and I want to understand what you said) Characterbody has a built I n move_and_slide use ng velocity so if i want to use it i have to use velocity.x / y, than my variables

Comment: @BadDev As pointed out, Godot 4's `CharacterBody2D` and `CharacterBody3D` have a `velocity` property that `move_and_slide` uses. So instead of passing an argument to `move_and_slide` you set the `velocity` property sometime before calling `move_and_slide`. in fact, `move_and_slide` no longer takes any arguments. This was done because it had too many optional ones, and was getting out of hand. By the way, you don't have to use `velocity.x` and `velocity.y`, you can do `velocity = target_position * speed`. *I would have used the name `direction` instead of `target_position`, by the way.*