# Line 47:Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 1

Tags: godot, godot4

So I'm following a tutorial to make the player move towards a StaticBody2D node, and there's a section in the script called "move_and_slide" where the player can move, but I'm getting an error.
Here is my full code:

```
func moveTowardsTarget():
    if position.distance_to(target_position) > 1:
        var direction = (target_position - position).normalized()
        var velocity = direction * move_speed
        move_and_slide(velocity)
```

The error is in the script section "move_and_slide(velocity)"
I've looked on Stack Overflow for this problem and I found a answer but this is for if i call a motion witch I don't so that doesn't help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move\_and\_slide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869903/godot-4-is-giving-me-the-error-of-too-many-arguments-in-move-and-slide)

Comment: The abstract is that you were watching a Godot 3 tutorial. Under the assumption that the question linked above is the one said you found, I have expanded the answer to add advice in adapting the code, and also in telling if you are looking at a Godot 3 tutorial or a Godot 4 tutorial. I would encourage looking for a Godot 4 tutorial, as you are likely to find further problems with the one you were watching.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send velocity as a parameter to the move_and_slide function. The function automatically applies the Body's velocity when you call it.

I've found the documentation to be very helpful with this kind of error. If you ctrl/cmd click on the move_and_slide() function call the documentation will open up giving advice on how to use the function, the expected parameters and also the return type.