# Having trouble understanding player movement with move_and_slide

Tags: gdscript

I'm currently making a pong game in Godot and I'm following a tutorial that uses Godot 3 instead of 4 to make pong, where I'm trying to move the player's paddle. I'm having trouble with the move_and_slide() method because it takes no parameters, whereas Godot 3 does have parameters for move_and_slide(). Not sure how to proceed because the tutorial code is not working. Here is the code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 400

func _physics_process(delta):
    var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
    move_and_slide(velocity * speed)
```

I tried removing the parameters of move_and_slide() but that still didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move\_and\_slide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869903/godot-4-is-giving-me-the-error-of-too-many-arguments-in-move-and-slide)