# Function for move the character2D in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

The error is in move_in_slide()

```
extends CharacterBody2D


var motion = Vector2(0, 0)
const speed = 50
const gravity = 50

const UP=Vector2(0,-1)

func _physics_process(delta):
    apply_gravity()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left") and not Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
        motion.x = speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right") and not Input.is_action_just_pressed("left"):
        motion.x = -speed
    else:
        motion.x=0

    move_and_slide(motion, UP)

func apply_gravity():
    if is_on_floor():
        motion.y=0
    else:
               motion.y +=gravity
```

I hope that solution my wrong. I am starting to learn Godot. I need help please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move\_and\_slide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869903/godot-4-is-giving-me-the-error-of-too-many-arguments-in-move-and-slide)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Godot 4, in which case `move_and_slide()` should take in 0 arguments. Try replacing `move_and_slide(motion, UP)` with simply `move_and_slide()`.