# how to solve Godot smooth movement error that keeps appearing with velocity saying that it is already native to characterBody2D

Tags: godot

extends CharacterBody2D

const MAX_SPEED = 400
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
# Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
# As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
var direction = Vector2.ZERO
direction.x = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left") #direction1 represent the x axis
direction.y = Input.get_action_strength("ui_down") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up") #direction2 represent the y axis

```
if direction != Vector2.ZERO:
    velocity = direction
else:
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO

move_and_slide(velocity * delta)
```

i can't stop velocity becoming an error
someone said i should add (velocity = velocity.move_toward(input_vector * MAX_SPEED, ACCELERATION) * delta) but i don't know where

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 4 is giving me the error of too many arguments in move\_and\_slide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869903/godot-4-is-giving-me-the-error-of-too-many-arguments-in-move-and-slide)

Answer (score 1):

The velocity identifier should be used instead of parameters for move_and_slide()

You can do

```
velocity = velocity * delta
move_and_slide()
```

instead of adding a parameter to move_and_slide().

"velocity" is used as the parameter for move_and_slide(). They changed that in Godot 4